# Will Dropbox delete malware in my uploads?

Tags: malware, dropbox

I'm doing some reverse engineering research, which including some malware. Can I save them in my Dropbox? Will Dropbox delete them from the server end? I searched around but haven't found a clear answer. Thanks.

Comment: Dropbox syncs from your local computer and it is your local file that should be checked with your antivirus.

Comment: @John I know that. My question is, if I upload malware to Dropbox server, will Dropbox delete them?

Comment: I am not certain about that. You might wish to try and see what happens.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about whether a cloud service has a specific feature, not about the software on the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox doesn't scan your files with an antivirus, as stated in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/8406). So your malware files **will not** be deleted.

Source from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83673)